# Different forms depending on object status in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a model `Order` with field `status`. Depending on the status of the order, the user should see something different when he/she tries to update the order.

So if the order is pending, I want to show some fields and when the user successfully submits the form, the order status should change to another status, etc.

I guess I can use an UpdateView and override `get_form_class`, `form_valid`, and `get_template_names`. In get_form_class I can return the form class to use depending on the status and in form_valid I can make sure the status will change to the new status.

Is this the best approach? Or should I make separate views for each use case?

When the order is accepted, I want the user to confirm which actually doesn't require any fields. So maybe it's better to use separate views for each use case or what?

Comment: Do you actually have different forms or do you just want to display more or less fields depending on the status? What have you tried?

Comment: You don't have to overwrite forn_valid and get_templatenames. Let your template always render `{{ form }}` and let the form validation be done by the form, you passed with `get_form_class`.

Answer (score 0):

If the forms are very different from each other, then write 2 separate forms and pass them depending on the status. You do not need 2 different views for that. I split views based on functionality, so again, if both forms are to satisfy two different purposes, then maybe its better to serve them from different views.

Another approach is use a single form and in the template you can render the form fields manually to show fields depending on your different statuses. [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) is more info about splitting your fields.

Comment: _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._